# How do I differentiate between old and new data in backbone collections?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript

A common pattern I come across is a backbone collection which is initially seeded from a database.

However, the user can also add to the collection. When the user does add to the collection, these should be reflected in the db.

Usually I would bind some kind of server call to the collection `add` event. However if I do that, the call will be made even during the initial seed. I only want it to be called on *new* data.

Whats the right way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you bind to a local function, which checks the value of an `isDataLoading` variable/property/method-call *before* making the server-side call?

Comment: @jimbobmcgee I could, but how do I update that variable? How do I tell when the collection has completed loading the seed data? Also, there's the possibility of a user quickly adding to the collection before the seed data is fully loaded.

Comment: How is the data getting from your database to your collection?  You must be loading it in somehow.  Set it before and after that.

Comment: As for preventing users from modifying data before you're ready, have the `isDataLoading` variable control visibility and/or enabled state of your controls / have the state-changing controls check the `isDataLoading` variable in their event handlers, before updating state / create the controls dynamically only after you've seeded the collection.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I tell when the collection has completed loading the seed data?

Define an `initialize` function:

```
var foo = new Backbone.Model({
  "Name": "foo"
});

var bar = new Backbone.Collection(null, {
  model: foo,
  initialize: baz
  }
});
```

> Also, there's the possibility of a user quickly adding to the collection before the seed data is fully loaded:

Use a separate model for the user-generated content:

```
function callback(event)
  {
  callback.model = new Backbone.Model({"Name":event.target.value});
  }
```

Then use `set` to merge them when initialize is called:

```
function baz()
  {
  try
    {
    foo.set({"Name": callback.model.get("Name")});
    }
  catch(e)
    {
    console.log(e);
    }
  }
```